# LEFT JOIN with LIMIT

Tags: mysql, left-join, limit

I have two tables A and A_LOG

The relation is N A_LOG to 1 A

The A table is:
a_id,
slogan

The A_LOG table is:
a_log_id,
a_id,
data

Inside the **A table** i have:

```
a_id | slogan
   1 | bla
   2 | bla bla
   3 | bla bla bla
   4 | bla bla bla bla
```

Inside the **A_LOG table** I have:

```
a_log_id | a_id | data
       1 |   1  | 2012-01-01
       2 |   1  | 2013-01-01
       3 |   3  | 2012-02-01
       4 |   3  | 2013-02-01
```

When I do the **left join** I get

```
 a_id | slogan              | data
    1 | bla                 | 2012-01-01
    1 | bla                 | 2013-01-01
    2 | bla bla             | NULL
    3 | bla bla bla         | 2012-02-01
    3 | bla bla bla         | 2013-02-01
    4 | bla bla bla bla     | NULL
```

**What I want**:

```
     a_id | slogan              | data
        1 | bla                 | 2013-01-01
        2 | bla bla             | NULL
        3 | bla bla bla         | 2013-02-01
        4 | bla bla bla bla     | NULL
```

I'm using a simple left join, I also tried to do a left join (select from A_LOG order by data DESC LIMIT1), but that limited the amount of joins it made.

I tried to make myself clear with an abstract example, many of the others I saw were confusing since they were using personal environments.
My real situation has a lot of others joins and stuff, but this is the problem and I would like to isolate and solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT A.a_id, A.slogan, max(AL.data) data
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN A_LOG AL ON A.a_id = AL.a_id
GROUP BY A.a_id, A.slogan
```

Comment: @bacoco . . . This looks correct to me.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle to show how it is not working?